# Create datasource in azure search returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a search service running on azure in a free tier. On this service I already have a datasource, and indexer and an index defined.
I'd like to add another datasource (and index + indexer). When I do this (using postman) I get 403 Forbidden without any other error message.

This is the POST I made to this url - https://my-search-service-name.search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2016-09-01:

```
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"api-key": "API-KEY-HERE"

{
    "name": "datasource-prod",
    "description": "Data source for search",
    "type": "azuresql",
    "credentials": { "connectionString" : "Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxx_prod;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx!;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" },
    "container": {"name": "DataAggregatedView"},
    "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": {
      "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",  
      "highWaterMarkColumnName" : "ChangeIndicator" 
    },
    "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": {
        "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.SoftDeleteColumnDeletionDetectionPolicy",
        "softDeleteColumnName" : "isDeleted",
        "softDeleteMarkerValue" : "0"
    }
}
```

Using the same request, with different name and database name worked perfectly and generated the existing (first) datasource. This error (403) - not even got the error message - happens only when I try to define a second datasource. 
As I can understand from documentation, free search tier allows 3 datasources. Anyone had this issue? Any help/direction is appreciate!

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you're using the *admin* API key. It looks like you may be using a query key.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how happened that postman changed that key! As I told you, the same body request was used to create the first datasource!